# Share Prisma types with frontend application?

Tags: node.js, prisma2

I've been looking at [Prisma](http://www.prisma.io) (Nodejs ORM) and have been wondering how to share the autogenerated TypeScript types with a front-end application. As far as I can tell, the Prisma client auto-generates all DTOs but offers no simple way to export or expose them to other parts of the stack?

Comment: Are you creating a REST API or a GraphQL one ? On the second hypothesis you can use [graphql-codegen](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/)